# casting out-of-range int to char. Is loss of precision really a question mark?

Tags: java, casting, char

I have my head stuck in the SCJP 6 Study guide, and am confused about a point they make here.

Regarding casting ints to chars, they say that the following are perfectly legal, but you get a loss of precision (which I can totally understand):

```
    char d = (char)-98;
    char c = (char)70000;
    System.out.println("d = " + d + " c = " + c);
```

The result of this is:

```
d = ? c = ?
```

The point here that I am confused on is that the resultant char value is printing out as just a question mark in both cases.  I would have expected a nonsensical numeric value, possibly bearing little or no relation at all to the original value, but nevertheless numeric.

Why is the result a question mark? I don't understand how just a question mark is a "loss of precision" here?

I have looked at many char related questions here on SO, and also googled a lot, but can't find an answer to this.

Does it differ with other JVM's? Or is it the standard response to all out-of-range char casts?

Comment: I guess the problem is that the console where you tried this code doesn't support unicode. Try this line at the end: `System.out.println("d = " + (int)d + " c = " + (int)c);`

Comment: Aaahh.. - yes that did indeed give me a printout more like what I was expecting.  d = 65438 c = 4464.  I was using Eclipse with java 7 on a windows 7 box. I'm surprised that doesn't support unicode, but clearly not, as your suggestion worked a treat.  So much weirdness..  ;-))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you append a char to a String, the char is appended ('a' for example), and not its numeric value (97 for example). If you want to know what the numeric value of the char is, use

```
System.out.println("d = " + ((int) d) + " c = " + ((int) c));
```

Comment: I knew I've should post an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys - Luiggi included.  ;-))

Comment: @PenelopeTheDuck you're welcome. Since you're studying for the SCJP 6 exam, it would be better if you run some Java code on Windows and Linux to compare how the JVM behaves in different OS.

Comment: Hmm - fair point.  I guess there will be quite a few subtle (or maybe even not-so-subtle) differences.  Thanks again for your help and advice.  :-)

Answer (score 3):

If you cast those chars back to ints, you'll see that they have the values 65438 and 4464 respectively.  Those correspond to the Unicode characters U+FF9E HALFWIDTH KATAKANA VOICED SOUND MARK and U+1170 HANGUL JUNGSEONG WE.  You get question marks when you print them as characters because your system just doesn't have a font that provides glyphs for those characters.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - it is very helpful.  Sadly as I am new I can't yet vote things up.  :-(  But thanks.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

the chars are actually `ff9e` and `1170`, they should appear to be

[image]
[image]

it's just that your system can't display them.

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/ff9e/index.htm

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1170/index.htm

Comment: Thanks for your answer - it is very helpful.  Sadly as I am new I can't yet vote things up.  :-(  But thanks.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println((char)65);
```

prints out

> A

So casting with loss precision is not question-mark, it is the char representation of the value that made it into the char after casting is applied.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - it is very helpful.  Sadly as I am new I can't yet vote things up.  :-(    But thanks.  :-)

Comment: @PenelopeTheDuck: Glad that it was helpful.